# Add a value to all elements in a list (R)

Tags: r, list, addition

I have a list like so:

```
a = list('bla'=c(0,1,2,3))
```

I want to add 1 to every element so

```
> a['bla']
$bla
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Of course

```
> a['bla']+1
```

doesn't work...

Help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need double brackets:

```
a[['bla']]+1
```

Compare:

```
R> a["bla"]
$bla
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

with

```
R> a[["bla"]]
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

As Dason points out, the reason you need the double brackets is that when operating on a list the single brackets returns a list containing the elements you asked for whereas the double brackets returns the element itself. You can't use arithmetic operators on lists directly so when you use the single brackets you get a list back and it doesn't know how to 'add 1' to a list.

Other ways of accessing a list element are:

- index: `a[[1]]`
- double: `a$bla`

Comment: Note that the reason you need the double brackets is that when operating on a list the single brackets returns a list containing the elements you asked for whereas the double brackets returns the element itself.  You can't use arithmetic operators on lists directly so when you use the single brackets you get a list back and it doesn't know how to 'add 1' to a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dollar sign to access list elements by name :

```
R> a$bla+1
[1] 1 2 3 4
```